# Font is different in WP7 and WP8 project

Tags: windows-phone-7, fonts, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

this is quite a strange thing I've run into.
I've been developing Windows Phone Apps for over a year now, and even with the WP8 switch i never seen this before.

If i take my WP 7.1 app and upgrade it to WP 8 the font gets quite messed up, shown in the two screenshots below. (Both taken from my WP8 Lumia 620)

1. WP 7.1 Version -

[image]

2. WP 8 Version -

[image: http://i105.photobucket.com/albums/m218/MegaNight2006/wp_ss_20130423_00021_zps1f419533.png]

Quite strange indeed, the font used is "visitor1 TT1 BRK"
from http://www.dafont.com/visitor.font

The font is set as a BlendEmbeddedFont and used in XAML like this:

```
FontFamily="/TronRadio;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Visitor TT1 BRK"
```

Is it a .NET 4.5 thing that needs to be set or some other kind of problem?
It is the first time I've seen this problem, i have upgraded other apps with embedded fonts without running into this.

One note is that the font shows up fine in the Design Workplace (Visual Studio 2012 and Blend).
However on the Windows Phone 8 and Emulators the above problems shows.

Thanks

Comment: For WP8 it looks like it's not applying the font and therefore it falls back to Segoe. There will be probably a difference in the syntax. What that is I don't know, but I hope it will make your search a bit easier

Comment: So after a long time, and much trying i gave up.
Untill this thing happent again with Buxton Sketch Font in my newst app, i had another go after it just suddenly did this random stuff again after days of working fine with the font.
I seem to have fixed it with unselecting Auto Fill from the font manager in Blend

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you select the font in Expression Blend and then **Embed** it separately for Windows Phone 7 and 8 apps. This might help.

Comment: I am not sure, but I hope it is not because of the space in the name of the file. Once I had such a problem,  a friend suggested this. But eventually I shifted to another font and I did not try his solution. Just try it once. :p

Comment: And even try this, set font location to **"/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Visitor TT1 BRK"**

Comment: Nope no such luck.
I don't think this is the right direction, as you can see the font is loaded, and used some of the time however, it's rather random in picking when to use the font.